# Mongoose find if an array element is in another array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How do I check if an element of an array belongs to another array in Mongoose.
For example, I have a document:

`{"_id":"","username":"","password":"","email":"","image":"1-81-14.svg","dob":"","marital_status":"","phone":"","categories":["catering_services","legal_services","computer_programmers","rentals","fashion_designers","education"]}`

and another document of the same collection:

`{"_id":"","username":"","password":"","email":"","image":"1-81-14.svg","dob":"","marital_status":"","phone":"","categories":["computer_programmers","rentals","fashion_designers","education", "music"]}`

How do I check if at least an element of the array in the categories node in the first document belongs to the array in the second document